# how to change content using id from hash url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser, url-rewriting

I'm using

```
var integer = window.location.hash.match(/\d+/) | 0;
alert(integer);
```

to get id from the hash url but when i use back button after changing the url after ajax call.
It doesn't reflect any change, basically page remains in same state and only the url changes.

so, what i want to know is that how to change the content when i use back button.
Or simply show the integer in alert box when i use back button that's it.

e.g.

```
http://test.php/#1
```

show 1 when i get to that page using back button

```
http://test.php#2
```

show 2 when i get to that page using back button

```
 http://test.php
```

show 0 when i get to that page using back button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to catch the [`window.onhashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) event, or use HTML5's [`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) methods.

Or just use the jQuery history plugin.

Comment: its showing output when i change the content from non hash page to hash page like test1.com to test1.com/#1
but i want to make changes from test1.com/#2 to test1.com/#1

Comment: @SobhagyaMohanty yes, so you have to catch `window.onhashchange` and reload the right AJAX content for the new value of `window.location.hash`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle the `hashchange` event of `window`. Something like:

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
    // Update the page
};
```

Or you can use `addEventListener` and `attachEvent`. Be warned, though, it doesn't work in IE7 or earlier! For earlier IE compatibility, you need a hack like [this one](http://www.zachleat.com/web/onhashchange-without-setinterval/).